# JavaScript: How to rebuild text from an inverted index?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, inverted-index

I have an inverted index in the following format:

```
{
 IndexLength: 5,
 InvertedIndex: {
  word1: [0, 2, 4],
  word2: [1, 3]
 }
}
```

What is the most efficient way of transforming this into "word1 word2 word1 word2 word1" string using JavaScript?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use two `forEach()` loops to create array and then use `join()` to get string.

```js
var obj = {IndexLength: 5,InvertedIndex: {word1: [0, 2, 4],word2: [1, 3]}}

var arr = []
Object.keys(obj.InvertedIndex).forEach(k => obj.InvertedIndex[k].forEach(a => arr[a] = k))
console.log(arr.join(' '))
```

Comment: More simplified answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example to start with.

```js
var obj = {
  IndexLength: 5,
  InvertedIndex: {
    word1: [0, 2, 4],
    word2: [1, 3]
  }
}

var arr = [];

var temp = obj.InvertedIndex;

for (var key in temp) {
  if (temp.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
    temp[key].forEach(function(v) {
      arr[v] = key;
    });;
  }
}

console.log(arr.join(' '));
```